# Is "Hillarycare" typically derogatory?

Tags: united-states, terminology

Is the term "Hillarycare" typically used as a derogatory term?

I tried looking up the Wikipedia article on [Clinton health care plan of 1993](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinton_health_care_plan_of_1993), but it didn't discuss the term "Hillarycare".

Comment: Never heard the term, but obviously a dig at who wore the presidential pants back in '93

Comment: It wasn't so much intended as derogatory, as it was a label exclusively used by its opponents. So it acquired a negative context.

Answer (score 2):

It was derogatory at the time.  It still is as most Republicans believe Obamacare was modeled after HillaryCare.  While President Obama uses the term Obamacare in a non derogatory fashion, it is still used on the right as a derogatory term.

What sounds better, the Affordable Care Act or HillaryCare/ObamaCare?

Comment: We'll soon hear about "BillaryCare".